# SNMP pass script works but snmpget for OID doesn't provide correct result

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, snmp

I wrote a prototype script to start examining the status of a service using SNMP.  The script itself, seems to work, as I am using mysql as a test example, but the OID as requested via snmpget returns an incorrect value. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this, as I do not get any log messages saying there is an issue.  It doesn't give me an error about an unknown OID, so I believe the OID is registered with the snmp daemon.  Example output:

```
sudo service mysql stop
something:~ $ ./snmp-mysql 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.38.1
gauge
0
something:~ $ sudo service mysql start
something:~ $ ./snmp-mysql 
.1.3.6.1.2.1.38.1
gauge
1
something:~ $ snmpget -v2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.38.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.38.1 = Gauge32: 0
```

The pass-through MIB extension command portion of snmpd.conf has the following:

```
pass .1.3.6.1.2.1.38.1  /bin/sh /usr/local/bin/snmp-mysql
```

I have also been careful to make sure the script that is called is identical to the one in my directory so the idea of an incorrect script is removed from troubleshooting possibilities.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this issue because I'm not getting any feedback from snmpd and I have no idea how to put it in some kind of verbose mode for logging purposes.  Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the script, but I am unsure why it works.  Original script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-g" ]; then
    echo .1.3.6.1.2.1.38.1
    echo gauge
    OUTPUT="$(service mysql status | grep inactive)"
    if [[ ${OUTPUT} ]]; then
       echo 0
       # it is running
    else
        echo 1
        # it is not
    fi
fi
exit 0
```

Apparently the output is more than just the MIB, gauge, and the resultant 1 or 0 as the check itself outputs a line that is not visible.

The new file:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "-g" ]; then
    echo .1.3.6.1.2.1.38.1
    echo gauge
    if service mysql status | grep inactive > /dev/null; then
        echo 0
        # it is running
    else
        echo 1
        # it is not
    fi
fi
```

I came across a similar link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52800/how-to-do-an-if-statement-from-the-result-of-an-executed-command that included a comment that made reference to /dev/null.  Furthermore, swapping the script to a pass OID that was working gave me the same error and let me to check script issues instead of snmpd configuration issues.